# How to add a google-recaptcha v3 to a functional react component with a form?

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I have a ready-made form in React

I'm trying to add a captcha to it but it would seem that with the only correct option the captcha reload infinity loops

I didt think that in such a simple task in React there could be so many problems

```
import { GoogleReCaptchaProvider, GoogleReCaptcha } from 'react-google-recaptcha-v3'

type Props = {
  onSubmit: (values: AuthRequest) => Promise<AuthResponse>
}

function AuthForm(props: Props) {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('')
  return (
    <div className={cn('container')}>
      <GoogleReCaptchaProvider reCaptchaKey="[key]">
        <Form
          onSubmit={handlers.submit}
          render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <FormField name={'email'} />
              <div>
                <FormField name={'password'} />
              </div>
              <GoogleReCaptcha
                onVerify={(token) => {
                  setToken(token)
                }}
              />
              <div>
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
              </div>
            </form>
          )}
        />
      </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
    </div>
  )
}

export { AuthForm }
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it like this

```js
    import { GoogleReCaptchaProvider, GoogleReCaptcha } from 'react-google-recaptcha-v3'

    type Props = {
      onSubmit: (values: AuthRequest) => Promise<AuthResponse>
    }

    function AuthForm(props: Props) {
      const [token, setToken] = useState('')
      const verifyRecaptchaCallback = React.useCallback((token) => {
        setToken(token)
      }, []);
      return (
        <div className={cn('container')}>
          <GoogleReCaptchaProvider reCaptchaKey="[key]">
            <Form
              onSubmit={handlers.submit}
              render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <FormField name={'email'} />
                  <div>
                    <FormField name={'password'} />
                  </div>
                  <GoogleReCaptcha
                    onVerify={verifyRecaptchaCallback}
                  />
                  <div>
                    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              )}
            />
          </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
        </div>
      )
    }

    export { AuthForm }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't state it but I assume you are using `react-google-recaptcha-v3` ?

According to the documentation over at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha-v3

> // IMPORTANT NOTES: The `GoogleReCaptcha` component is a wrapper around `useGoogleRecaptcha` hook and use `useEffect` to run the verification. It's important that you understand how React hooks work to use it properly. Avoid using inline function for the `onVerify` props as it can possibly cause the verify function to run continously. To avoid that problem, you can use a memoized function provided by `React.useCallback` or a class method

I think the loop happens because the `GoogleReCaptcha` is causing itself to be rerendered by calling a callback that modifies the state of the parent element constantly. BTW, I tried wrapping `GoogleReCaptcha` in `React.memo()`, that didn't work (anyway, that's just optimization, not guaranteed to work, so a poor choice to protect unecessary API calls).

Since I am using class based components, none of the solutions to this type of problem really appealed to me. In the end, I solved this by simply not rendering `GoogleReCaptcha` after the first callback, something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        ...
        reCaptchaToken: null
    }
}

...

<GoogleReCaptchaProvider reCaptchaKey="[key]">
    ...
    { this.state.reCaptchaToken===null ?
        <GoogleReCaptcha
            onVerify={(reCaptchaToken) => {
                this.setState({reCaptchaToken:reCaptchaToken})
            }}
        />
    :
        ''
    }
    ...
</GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
```